# WebAPI URL is not routing as expected

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following two methods defined in my WebAPI controller:

```
public class SocketController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/socket")]
    public List<SocketInfo> GetAllSockets()
    {
        throw new Exception("Not Implemented; Use API/Socket/{ConfigId} to request a specific socket.");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/socket/{Id}")]
    public SocketInfo GetSocket(string configId)
    {
        SocketInfo si = new SocketInfo();
        si.ConfigId = configId;
        si.Password = "****************";
        si.SystemName = "_SystemName";
        si.Type = Definitions.SocketType.DTS;
        si.Subtype = Definitions.SocketSubtype.PUT;

        return si;
    }
    ...
```

As expected, the url https://localhost:44382/API/Socket returns the exception:

```
<Error>
   <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
   <ExceptionMessage>Not Implemented; Use API/Socket/{ConfigId} to request a specific socket. 
   </ExceptionMessage>
   <ExceptionType>System.Exception</ExceptionType>
   <StackTrace>
   ...
```

OK, let's try to retrieve a specific socket by Id: https://localhost:44382/API/Socket/ab24def6

But for some reason, this doesn't route. Here's what I get:

```
<Error>
   <Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
           'https://localhost:44382/API/Socket/ab24def6'.
   </Message>
   <MessageDetail>No action was found on the controller 'Socket' that matches the request. 
   </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is not routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
[HttpGet, Route("api/socket/{configId}")]
public SocketInfo GetSocket([FromRoute] string configId)
{
    // ...
}
```

The problem was that your parameter name didn't match the route parameter name. `[FromRoute]` is optional in this case, but it makes it clearer to the programmer where the data is to originate from.

Comment: Yes! I did not realize the the name of the parameter is integral to the routing signature. Everything working now as expected. (Thanks!)